# Seamlessly Attach UV Surfaces

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv

I have a surface with correct UV mapping, and I have another surface next to it which has its own UV mapping, but which I want to be aligned with the first, in both scale and position, so the texture between them becomes seamless.

Can this be done?

Currently I'd select both of them and give both a new UV projection so they'd be joined together and then adjust the scale and position again until I'm happy, re-doing this process evey time a new surface is created which needs to be a part of this one; it's not very efficent.

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Any reason to not model the surfaces based on the material so you only have to UV it once?

Comment: Hi :). To match the UV scale precisely, look into Texel Density addons (there's a few), it saves time considerably.

Comment: @DaleCieslak I'm sorry, I don't understand. What do you mean?

Comment: @JachymMichal Thanks for the suggestion; I'll look into it.

Comment: What I mean is, why model the floor in your image as two separate pieces where you need to match the UVs?  is there a reason to not model, say, the entire floor as one piece?

Comment: @DaleCieslak Sometimes I'm just extruding a piece out; in the above I subdevided one edge to get half the length and extruded out that part. But thinking about your comment, I could've just moved the edge even if there'd be redundent parts of geometry from the second half of the edge. Could work, I'll keep an eye open for it, thanks.